# HTML landing page in UPnP device

Tags: browser, embedded, upnp, lwip

I'm working with an embedded device that has rather limited capabilities. However It does have lwip stack as well as UPnP support. Problem is that currently transferring data out from the device is quite slow and I would like to minimize number of http requests sent e.g. when opening the landing page. Any idea how to optimize this ? Ideal way would be some compressed format but browser don't like that I guess.

Comment: What landing page are you referring to? That doesn't sound related to UPnP.

Comment: @jku I'd presumed this was referring to the (optional) presentation page for a UPnP device.

Comment: Assuming you control the HTTP server, you may be able to compress the data it returns if client requests include `Accept-Encoding: gzip`. Note that this would require reasonable processor bandwidth.  If your poor networking performance is caused by a slow processor, you'll have to try and simplify your presentation page instead.

Comment: MCU/CPU is STM32F407 but I think main bottle neck is the mass storage in the device that will hit hard on performance when downloading several small files (icons & stuff). I'm referring to landing page similar to routers/modem/printers have when you double click corresponding icon in the network neighborhood in Windows or write the IP address to browser 192.168.0.1 etc.
My presentation page is done with html+javascript and there could be possibility to simplify it a bit. Not sure how much though.